# WCF - MessageBodyMember - Stream - "Value cannot be null"

Tags: wcf, stream

I have a MessageContract containing one BodyMember.
When I try to send that message contract without initializing that BodyMember I get following excepton:

System.ArgumentNullException occurred
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: FileStream

If I change it to MessageHeader it will work (but I need it to stay BodyMember).
Is it possible that MessageBodyMember can't null or that Stream can't be null?

This is MessageContract:

```
[MessageContract]
public class AdsAdminRequest : ServiceMessageRequest
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public AdsAdminCriteria Criteria { get; set; }

    [MessageHeader]
    public AdDto Ad { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public Stream FileStream { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stream is a special case which means "everything in the message body". If you really want to send `null` (or `Nothing`), consider passing `Stream.Null`.

Comment: -1: According to the linked question, Stream.Null is not for returning in case of an error. Instead, one should consider throwing a custom-made FaultException<T> that includes information and is caught, instead of returning a proxy value.